# Update Image in Button in DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

In my model I have the following code to change a category through a dialog.

```
        internal DiagramCategory ChangeCategoryWithDialog()
        {
            DiagramCategory diagramCategory = DiagramCategory.Other;
            AddCategoryView diagramView = new AddCategoryView();
            bool? showDialog = diagramView.ShowDialog();
            if (showDialog.HasValue && showDialog.Value)
            {
                if (diagramView.DataContext is AddCategoryViewModel)
                {
                    AddCategoryViewModel addCategoryViewModel = (AddCategoryViewModel)diagramView.DataContext;
                    diagramCategory = addCategoryViewModel.SelectedCategory;
                }
            }
            return diagramCategory;
        }
```

This code works fine. In the viewmodel, where this method is called looks like:

```
 private void SelectCategory(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter is DiagramCategory && this.SelectedDiagramEntry != null)
            {
                DiagramCategory diagramCategory = this.financialModel.ChangeCategoryWithDialog();
                this.SelectedDiagramEntry.Category = diagramCategory;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDiagramEntry");
            }
        }
```

In the view I have a DataGridTemplateColumn with a button in a cell. The content of this button is an image. The xaml is

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category" SortMemberPath="Category">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button x:Name="categoryButton" Style="{StaticResource Flat}" Tag="{Binding Category}"
                                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectCategoryCommand, 
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=categoryButton, Path=Tag}">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Category, Converter={StaticResource categoryConverter}}"/>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The definition of the DataGrid is

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DiagramEntries}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDiagramEntry, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True" AlternationCount="2">
```

DiagramEntries is an ObservableCollection with DiagramEntries in it. The DiagramEntry-Class just contains four properties. The Category-Property is an custom enum.

My problem is, that the image inside the button in a datagridrow is not updated after the SelectCategory-Method is called. What am I doing wrong? I already tried to add a call to `OnPropertyChanged("Category")`. Unfortunately this also doesn't work

Comment: How is the `categoryConverter` implemented that is used in the Source-Binding of the Image?

Comment: It just takes the enum and delivers a ImageSource.